# Fast N-dimensional index conversion

Tags: c++, algorithm

What would be the fastest possible way to convert an integer (say **i**) into a coordinate in an **N**-dimensional matrix, using C++?

E.g. given **i** = 15, **N** = 3, matrix sizes = { **4, 3, 2** }, the result should be { **3, 0, 1**}.

The following approach has been used:

```
coord[n] = (i / stride[n]) % dimension_size[n],
```

where `stride[n]` is pre-calculated to be `dimension_size[0] * dimension_size[1] * ..dimension_size[n-1]`

Using division and modulo like this every time is not fast enough. Maybe there is a clever trick to do this really fast? Employ caching or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you benchmark...

Comment: Consider that you said "every time", I assume you have to do it repeatedly, but is hiding it from us. Describe your actual problem please. (avoid XY problem, you know) There may be some problem-specific ways to avoid recalculating the index.

Comment: Is `N` always going to be the same or not?

Comment: Please show us what you did so far. In this case the formula to come form `15` to `{3,0,1}`. Perhaps you can do the calculation at compile time using `constexpr`?

Comment: Use case is calculating matrix values based on some formulas. Matrices have different sizes, but there are rules how coordinates are mapped to each other. All matrices are stored as flat arrays. N can be considered fixed for a given calculation run.

Comment: _Describe your actual problem please._

Comment: Formula so far has been as follows: coord[n] = (i / stride[n]) % dimension_size[n], where stride[n] is pre-calculated to be dimension_size[1]*dimension_size[2]*..dimension_size[n-1]

Comment: Learn from the best. For example, looking at how NumPy implements [`unravel_index`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html), it seems that it boils down to the function `unravel_index_loop_corder` in [this source file](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/compiled_base.c), and it's just a loop using modulo and division. It doesn't imply it has to be impossible to do better, but it should indicate that it is, at the very least, a "good enough" method.

Comment: Describe your actual problem please. "calculating matrix values based on some formulas" usually for matrix operations, the array index is not the known, but the indices of the element in the matrix, so why is your code structured that you need this, and why is this a bottleneck (at least 10% of time of the run).

Comment: *"Use case is calculating matrix values based on some formulas"* Could you please show us an example of those formulas?

Comment: The full description of the problem would take too long. However here is a characteristic example: given matrix A{MxNxP}, calculate matrix B{QxRxM}, such that B[q][r][m] is equal to A[m][func1(r)][func2(q)]. Both matrices are represented as flat arrays.

Comment: Your performance problem is not due to coordinates conversion. What you have is the right algorithm. Much more likely, the order in which you access memory causes the slowness. You should access memory by locality. e.g. access memory close to what you accessed before.

Answer (score 1):

Your example

```
B[q][r][m] = A[m][func1(r)][func2(q)]
```

doesn't require inverting `i` to find q,r,m, but does have the least significant index of B mapped to the most significant index of A, so probably will have issues with cache. If you're implementing it by incrementing i and deriving q,r,m, then that has the same effect as incrementing q,r,m in nested loops, and it's probably faster to convert q,r,m to i than visa-versa, but unlikely to be the bottleneck.

Depending on size of data, it may be worth inverting A to begin with, or creating a slice of A with a fixed q in the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly; you are looking at how to index into a flat array that represents a multidimensional matrix?

Since matrices like arrays are stored contiguously in memory the general idea of indexing into a `MxN` matrix for row-major order has the following formula:

If a matrix `MxN` matrix has axes `(i,j)` then the index location of a flat array into the `MxN` matrix is `matrix[i][j] = array[i*M + j]`.

This idea can be generalized to higher dimensions:

If a matrix `MxNxO` has axes `(i,j,k)` then the index location of a flat
array into the `MxNxO` matrix is `matrix[i][j][k] = array[i*(N*M) + j*M + k]`

And this pattern will continue to follow for higher dimensional matrices.

If a matrix `MxNxOxP` has axes `(i,j,k,l)` then ... `matrix[i][j][k][l] = array(i*(O*N*M) + j*(N*M) + k*M + l)`.

Comment: I'm afraid that OP's problem is to find the inverses of those conversions.

Comment: @Bob__ Yes maybe so; but the op should be able to figure out the inverse of those formulas...